Almost sure convergence in Bayesian setting
Lets say I have a probability space with random variables X1,X2,.... These random variables have a parameter Θ. Given Θ, X1,X2,... are iid. This implies that conditional on Θ, the sample mean converges almost surely to E[X|Θ] (due to SLLN). If we treat Θ as a random variable (as we do in a Bayesian setting), would the sample mean converge almost surely to anything when not conditioned on Θ? Would it converge to E[E[X|Θ]] (where the outer expectation is w.r.t the prior distribution of Θ)? I'm guessing if it does converge to E[E[X|Θ]], the prior would have to satisfy some conditions. What would those conditions be?

What does your prior represent?  You can think of this as a two-step model:



Generate $\theta \sim \text{your prior}    $




Generate $X_1, X_2, \dotsc$ using the generated value of $\theta$, that is, as IID $f(x \mid \theta)$



This should make it clear that as soon as $\theta$ is generated, and its generated value is used at step 2., its distribution does not play a role anymore. So, by the SLLN, the sample mean should converge to  $ E[X\mid \theta]$.
In your last paragraph you ask about what happens if not conditioning on
$\theta$. It is not clear to me what that could mean, and what relevance it could have. You need to elaborate on that in your question. At least, you need to augment the two-step model.
